# Using Recaptcha with EPiServer XForms

Tags: recaptcha, xforms, episerver

Does any one have experiense of using Recaptcha with XForms in EPiServer?

I don't know where to put the Recaptcha control and how to make it work. The sample code for ASP.NET is the code below. Where should i put it. My guess is in the `FormControl_BeforeSubmitPostedData`?

```
 <%@ Page Language="VB" %>
 <%@ Register TagPrefix="recaptcha" Namespace="Recaptcha" Assembly="Recaptcha" %>  
 <script runat=server%gt;       
 Sub btnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)           
    If Page.IsValid Then               
        lblResult.Text = "You Got It!"               
        lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Green           
    Else               
        lblResult.Text = "Incorrect"               
        lblResult.ForeColor = Drawing.Color.Red           
    End If       
 End Sub   
 </script>   
 <html>   
 <body>       
 <form runat="server">           
     <asp:Label Visible=false ID="lblResult" runat="server" />
     <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID="recaptcha" runat="server" Theme="red"
                                 PublicKey="your_public_key" PrivateKey="your_private_key" />
     <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
 </form>   
 </body>   
 </html>
```

Answer (score 7):

I've had some experience with modifying the output of XForms within EPiServer, but I have not added any captcha controls before. I hope I can help you get there!

I do all modification of the XForms output on the XFormControl.BeforeLoadingForm event. You can assign an event handler to this either within the Global.asax.cs or create a static initializer class that instantiates the first time somebody navigates onto a form page (my template class inherits from this initialiser class.) I only did this because I needed a nice deployable solution without changing Global.asax. Anyway, I digress.

For now, I'd suggest doing it within the Global.asax.cs just to get you working. There is example code within the Global.asax.cs that is installed with the PublicTemplates pack. Look for the 'Global XFrom Events' region.

The 'markup' of the XForm is exposed though the BeforeLoadingForm event arguments.

```
e.FormDefinition
```

Modifying this string will change the rendered output of the form, regardless of what the user created within the XForm editor. For example:

```
e.FormDefinition += "<asp:HyperLink runat=\"server\" Text=\"HyperLink\" />";
```

This example obviously adds markup to what currently exists, but you can completely transform the original markup if you wish. (I use regex to transform the tables into div/fieldset tags)

I hope this helps you get to your solution.

Example code for Global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XFormControl.ControlSetup += new EventHandler(XForm_ControlSetup);
}

public void XForm_ControlSetup(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    XFormControl control = (XFormControl)sender;

    control.BeforeLoadingForm += new LoadFormEventHandler(XForm_BeforeLoadingForm);
}

public void XForm_BeforeLoadingForm(object sender, LoadFormEventArgs e)
{
    XFormControl formControl = (XFormControl)sender;

    //We set the validation group of the form to match our global validation group in the master page.
    formControl.ValidationGroup = "XForm";

    e.FormDefinition += "<asp:HyperLink runat=\"server\" NavigationUrl=\"#\" Text=\"HyperLink\" />";
}
```

EDIT:

Sorry, the above code will help you integrate the captcha control into your form but completely missed out the part of actually checking whether the captcha control input is valid before submitting the form!

I agree that you would perform a check on the control within XFormControl.BeforeSubmitPostedData. Then if the captcha is not valid output an error message and set e.CancelSubmit to true.

RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

I may be simplifying things too much but this is a quick example of what I think you need. In your XForm user control code you need something similar to this:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnInit(e);

    this.FormControl.BeforeLoadingForm += new LoadFormEventHandler(FormControl_BeforeLoadingForm);
    this.FormControl.BeforeSubmitPostedData += new SaveFormDataEventHandler(FormControl_BeforeSubmitPostedData);
}

void FormControl_BeforeLoadingForm(object sender, LoadFormEventArgs e)
{
    e.FormDefinition += "<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl runat=\"server\" id=\"CaptchaControl\" />";
}

void FormControl_BeforeSubmitPostedData(object sender, SaveFormDataEventArgs e)
{
    /* find the captcha control e.g. FormControl.FindControl("CaptchaControl") or otherwise
     * test if the control is valid
     * if not valid e.CancelSubmit = true (show error etc.)
     */
}
```

As for the above example, as long as you have the Recaptcha control registered in your web.config or at the top of your template/usercontrol markup then it should work. You should find that the captcha control is just added onto the end of the form (probably not where you really want it to be, but this can be changed in your own way as long as you can pinpoint where you want to insert it within the e.FormDefinition string.

Where "FormControl" is the XForm control within your user control markup.

EDIT (23/12/2010):

The captcha control must be registered within the web.config NOT at the top of the markup file.

```
<add tagPrefix="recaptcha" namespace="Recaptcha" assembly="Recaptcha" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time James! I have a few more stupid questions. In the project i have XForm.ascx.cs where there are methods like FormControl_AfterSubmitPostedData. Can't i put your XForm_BeforeLoadingForm in there? A second question, i guess i put the Recaptcha control in the form with e.FormDefinition = <recaptcha:RecaptchaControl> but how and where do i register that control? Thanks again!

Comment: Andy, the two events you should be interested in are FormControl.BeforeLoadingForm and FormControl.BeforeSubmitPostedData. If you want, you can just set event handlers for these in your XFrom.ascx.cs (set them directly to your XForm control within your ASCX markup) but you will have to make sure you set them within the user controls OnInit().

The addition of the RecaptchaControl must be done within FormControl.BeforeLoadingForm. You only need to make sure that the control is registered within the template or in the web.config in the normal fashion. I will update my answer above.

Comment: Again, thank you! Your help has been very usful to me. I will sit down and try i out. Maybe i will have some more questions later on :) Thanks.

Comment: James, i have added this but get error: can not create form. public void FormControl_BeforeLoadingForm(object sender, LoadFormEventArgs e) { e.FormDefinition += "<recaptcha:RecaptchaControl ID=\"recaptcha\" runat=\"server\" Theme=\"red\" PublicKey=\"6Leh0r8SAAAAAGal7dz1wtBy2fsgQXfGGd3B0joU\" PrivateKey=\"6Leh0r8SAAAAAL_e8OHo4_oe6OxghxU-vXCWYnLq\" /> "; }

Comment: Andy - just tried this myself and discovered you need to register the captcha controls in the web.config NOT the ASPX/ASCX. This should fix your 'cannot create form' error.

Comment: James - Cheers, that worked! Another question, now i'm trying to find the control in the BeforeSubmitPostedData event. I have tried both FormControl recaptcha = FormControl.FindControl("recaptcha"); and Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl recaptcha = FormControl.FindControl("recaptcha") as Recaptcha.RecaptchaControl; In the first example i get the error that FormControl is a filed but used as a type. In the last example recaptcha is null. Any tips?

Comment: I'm not too sure where in the control hierarchy the recaptcha control will appear. I can't confirm it right now (could try it tomorrow) but I'd try recursively searching for the control within the XForms control. You will have to implement a 'FindControlRecursive' method yourself. Here's an example though, this should work: http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1663.htm

Comment: I discovered something intresting to day when i was going to implement my FindControlRecursive method. BeforeSubmitPostedData will only be hit when the Recaptcha is enterd with a correct value. If not correct, a standard errormessage is shown saying try again in the Recaptcha. No need to do any manual check then i guess?

Answer (score 3):

If the goal is to prevent spam a more accessible way is to check the form input using  Akismet. We have done this for XForms in EPiServer for multiple customers and it works great.

An article on why CAPTCHA isn't good for accessibility:
http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200709/provide_an_accessible_alternative_if_you_must_use_a_captcha/

Comment: Johan, thanks for your input. I will take a look at Akismet and talk to my customer. It's not free is it?

Comment: Hi Johan, note that this article is from 2007 and is now outdated, since reCAPTCHA now supports an audio alternative, as suggested by the article. So I wouldn't say that reCAPTCHA now posses a major accessibility concern.

Comment: Andy: It's free in some cases but yes, for normal business use it has a cost.

Comment: Alessandro: That's better yes, but still, having your user interpret/listen and put that in a field is always an obstacle.